# Mono-alphabetic Subsitution Encrypt using STL, cs106l

Tags: c++, stl

Im doing the exercises in CS106L about STL algorithms, one of the question ask about substitution encrypt by using random_shuffle.

The Questions is 
Using the random_shuffle implement a function MonoalphabeticSubstitutionEncrypt that accepts a source string and encrypts it with a random Monoalphabetic Substitution Cipher.

That means at the beginning I have
"AB..XYZ" and just called random_shuffle to A-Z
and generate something like "KVDQ...MSB"
and then do the mapping that encrypt the original string.

I can do it using mapping, but it should be done by using those STL algorithms only.

Anyone have ideas? Thank you!

I do it in this way, but seems like im not using the power of STL algorithm

```
string MonoSubsitutionEncrypt(string line){
    string original = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string excrypt = original;
    random_shuffle(encrypt.begin(), encrypt.end());
    map<char, char> m;
    for (int i = 0;i < original.length(); i++) 
        m.insert(make_pair(original[i],encrypt[i]));
    string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
         result += m[line[i]];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 I like the professor who gave you the assignment. Good to hear that professors are promoting STL algorithms :)

Comment: Usually people "forget" the homework tag.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a version of this that randomly shuffles bytes into other bytes.  You would have to go through some hoops to get it to only accept and output ascii characters.  I treated the null character specially because it should be preserved to indicate the end of the string.

Pseudocode for my algorithm is as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template class Filler (T)
    constructor Filler(T item)
        initial = item

    T operator () ()
        return initial++

    private T initial

template class Encryptor (T1, T2)
    constructor Encryptor(T1 mapping)
        cipher = mapping

    T2 operator () (T2 value)
        return cipher[value]

    private T1 cipher

int main (int c, char * v[])
    // stl class, big enough to hold each char
    vector<unsigned char> alphabet(256)       

    // creates a filler object described above
    Filler<unsigned char> filler(0)           

    // stl function, fills alphabet with one of each char
    generate_n(alphabet.begin(), 256, filler) 

    // stl function, shuffles alphabet (start at 1, leave NULL character at beginning)
    random_shuffle(alphabet.begin() + 1, alphabet.end())

    // creates a generator to be passed to transform
    Encryptor<vector<unsigned char>, unsigned char> e(alphabet)

    // get input value: either first parameter, or nothing if no parameters
    string input = c > 1 ? v[1] : ""

    // stl function, uses encryptor containing alphabet mapping to obfuscate input
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), e)

    // printing the string yields garbled crap
    cout << input << endl;
```

Documentation for stl classes used:
[string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
[vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)
[ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/)

Documentation for stl methods used: [generate_n](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/) [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) [transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/)

If this post gives away too much, someone edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a mapping class that creates and shuffles an array/vector upon creation, and overloads `operator()` to return the encrypted version of an input. To be of much use, you'll also need a member function (or perhaps operator) to retrieve the scrambled alphabet to use as a key for decryption.

With that, it should be pretty trivial to do the encryption itself with `std::transform`.

Comment: yaaa.. thats what i think too but is it possible to not use mapping, and just using STL? Can we do better?

Comment: @TimothyLeung: Given that a monoalphabetic substitution *is* a mapping, a mapping is certainly the obvious way to do it. I suppose something else *could* be done, but it'd have to be something pretty impressive to qualify as "better".